# I am trying to make a code that counts and i get the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with arrows pointing to "from" in line one

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code. Everything works until I add the while loop on line 8. I have no clue how a loop on line 8 affects line 1. The error message is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and it points to the word "from" in line 1

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
global n
keyboard = Controller()
n = 3321
time.sleep(5)

while n < 3325:
    a, b, c, d = str(n)
    keyboard.press(a)
    keyboard.release(a)
    keyboard.press(b)
    keyboard.release(b)
    keyboard.press(c)
    keyboard.release(c)
    keyboard.press(d)
    keyboard.release(d)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    n += 1
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the  **complete, exact error message**. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking for free help to solve your problem, so it's in your best interest to provide the relevant information to make it as easy as possible for us to do so.

Comment: Please try to remove the `global n` line. This declaration becomes only necessary inside a class or function/method that uses the global n variable

Comment: I tried to remove the global n line and nothing changed